# Excel, static column reference but updating rows

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

My issue revolves around dynamic vs static references in excel that goes beyond $A$2 type stuff.

I have two tabs, for this example we will call the first tab MAIN and the second tab COMMENT.  I have a cell in MAIN that I always want to look to a cell in Column B in the COMMENT tab.  For this example we will say B2.  When a new comment is entered in B2 the older comments shift to the right C2, D2, etc.  The I don't want the cell in MAIN to update the column reference.  My formula is this:

```
=INDEX(COMMENT!$B:$B,2)
```

However, if I have dozens of rows and when a new row is inserted I want the Cell Row Reference to update.  So if in the formula above the information in Row 2 got shifted to Row 3, I would need the formula to update to Row 3 but continue only looking in Column B.

```
=INDEX(COMMENT!$B:$B,3)
```

I’m close, the column reference works but the row reference doesn't update which shifts all the comments into the wrong cells in Main.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ROW()` function to return the row number.

```
=INDEX(COMMENT!$B:$B, ROW())
```

Comment: The ROW function with that syntax isn't working.

Comment: However, I got the syntax figured out and it works now, thank you.  The final formula looks like this: =INDEX(COMMENT!$B:$B, ROW(COMMENT!2:2))

Comment: @SteBe if you have solved your problem, please post that as an answer (you can also upvote Mark's answer if you feel it was useful) :)

Answer (score 0):

I got the syntax figured out and it works now, thank you.

The final formula looks like below:

```
=INDEX(COMMENT!$B:$B, ROW(COMMENT!2:2))
```